# Dynamically embed a flow in a page

Tags: apex, visualforce, flow, dynamic-vf-component, visual-flows

I want to embed a flow in a Visualforce page. I have 4 flows in place and a page parameter decides the flow that needs to be embedded in the page. So it is like dynamically deciding the flow to be launched.

Though my controller reads the page attribute for the flow name, the below is not possible in a VF page:

```
<flow:interview name="{!NameOfTheFlow}"/>
```

as the name attribute can only be a literal. Can someone suggest any workaround for the above problem?

Comment: Try having 4 different flows and hiding the ones you don't need with booleans instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround could be making a masterflow initiating the appropriate flow. You then only have to start this masterflow, and passing the name of the 'subflow' as a parameter:

```
<flow:interview name="StartAppropriateFlow">
    <apex:param name="flowName" value="{!NameOfTheFlow}" />
</flow:interview>
```

[image]

hope this helps. Note that subflows cannot have their own or dynamic finishlocations, so that might be the next issue

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with flows but haven't integrated them with VF pages, so might be I am missing something here, but can't we use literal names only in flow and render them using rendered attribute of outputPanel? Something like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!renderFlow}">
    <flow:interview name="Flow1"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!renderFlow}">
    <flow:interview name="Flow2"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```